# Python .replace() function, removing backslash in certain way

Tags: python

I have a huge string which contains emotions like "\u201d", AS WELL AS "\advance\"

all that I need is to remove back slashed so that:

```
- \u201d = \u201d
- \united\ = united
```

(as it breaks the process of uploading it to BigQuery database)

I know it should be somehow this way:

```
string.replace('\','') But not sure how to keep \u201d emotions.
```

**ADDITIONAL:**
Example of Unicode emotions

- \ud83d\udc9e
- \u201c
- \u2744\ufe0f\u2744\ufe0f\u2744\ufe0f

Comment: escape the backslahes with \\?

Comment: @DirtyBit both BUT I need to keep backslash next to emotions - "\u201d"

Comment: Do the emotions have something in common? Such as starting with the same letter ? (u)

Comment: @AriCooper-Davis Yes, exactly, you was right, this is the difficult part...

Comment: @BlueSheepToken yes they have started with "u" BUT it could be something like "\united\" which have to be removed

Comment: You might be able to use regex's .sub() using something like `r"(\\+\w+\\)"` which will find words delimited by \ on each side.

Comment: @alec_djinn As I have mentioned, I have a big string which contains strings like `\xxxx\`, I'm sorry I can't see the logic behind your answer, how does it work?

Comment: @AriCooper-Davis sorry, will it be like `.replace(r'(\\+\w+\\)','')`  or `.replace(r'(\\+\w+\\)','\w')` - sorry lack of knowledge

Comment: @AriCooper-Davis I have tested again right now and it could be ` advance\ ` database is still accepting this. But still stuck with the way to remove the first backslash  without touching emotions

Comment: \u2744\ufe0f\u2744\ufe0f\u2744\ufe0f what should be the output of this one?

Comment: @DeshDeepSingh as it is, I need to keep emotions and remove the rest backslashes

Comment: If this is impossible....then it is impossible...((

Comment: so how should output look like. i mean removing all the backslashes other than first? or just the last one?

Comment: @Bobbby I think this is what you are looking for, tell me if there are special cases I didnt take in account

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can split on all '\' and then use a regex to replace your emotions with adding leading '\'

```
s = '\\advance\\\\united\\ud83d\\udc9e\\u201c\\u2744\\ufe0f\\u2744\\ufe0f\\u2744\\ufe0f'
import re
print(re.sub('(u[a-f0-9]{4})',lambda m: '\\'+m.group(0),''.join(s.split('\\'))))
```

As your emotions are 'u' and 4 hexa numbers, `'u[a-f0-9]{4}'` will match them all, and you just have to add leading backslashes

First of all, you delete every '\' in the string with either `''.join(s.split('\\'))` or `s.replace('\\')`

And then we match every "emotion" with the regex `u[a-f0-9]{4}` (Which is u with 4 hex letters behind)

And with the regex sub, you replace every match with a leading `\\`

Answer (score 1):

You could simply add the backslash in front of your string after replacement if your string starts with `\u` and have at least one digit.

```
import re

def clean(s):

    re1='(\\\\)' # Any Single Character "\"
    re2='(u)'    # Any Single Character "u"
    re3='.*?'    # Non-greedy match on filler
    re4='(\\d)'  # Any Single Digit

    rg = re.compile(re1+re2+re3+re4,re.IGNORECASE|re.DOTALL)
    m = rg.search(s)

    if m:
        r = '\\'+s.replace('\\','')
    else:
        r = s.replace('\\','')
    return r


a = '\\u123'
b = '\\united\\'
c = '\\ud83d'

>>> print(a, b, c)
\u123 \united\ \ud83d

>>> print(clean(a), clean(b), clean(c))
\u123 united \ud83d
```

Of course, you have to split your sting if multiple entries are in the same line:

```
string = '\\u123 \\united\\ \\ud83d'
clean_string = ' '.join([clean(word) for word in string.split()])
```

Comment: That will fail, if this is the case you need to use regex to distinguish `u followed by a number` from the rest. But then please update your question to include this kind of input.

Comment: @Bobbby I have updated my answer. It looks for words starting with `\u` and containing at least one digit.

Comment: Sorry for late replay, this looks amazing, but regarding this `r = '\\'+s.replace('\\','')` as you treat string a it contain only specific value, how about string = `\u123    \united\    \ud83d`

Comment: That's very basic split and iterate. I am sure you can figure it out yourself. If not, in 1h I can post the solution.

Comment: But the again, edit your question, specify input and desired output please.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this simple method to replace the last occurence of your character  backslash:
Check the code and use this method.

```
def replace_character(s, old, new):
    return (s[::-1].replace(old[::-1],new[::-1], 1))[::-1]

replace_character('\advance\', '\','')
replace_character('\u201d', '\','')
```

Ooutput:

> \advance
>   \u201d

Answer (score 0):

You can do it as simple as this

```
text = text.replace(text[-1],'')
```

Here you just replace the last character with nothing